# Firebase Microsoft social auth not providing photoUrl

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Using firebase,  When I authenticate using Microsoft account I am not getting user photoURL in the firebase providerData object. Is there some steps missing? The account I am testing with is my own and does have profile picture.
I followed these instructions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I was have trouble as I debugged with curl because I missed the `$` in the URL which needed to be escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When integrating Firebase auth with MS Azure ID, a subsequent download of the photo binary must be performed by the front end using Microsoft's [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-beta#request).  Per firebase's [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth#before_you_begin), the firebase library will expose the token you need to pass to the MS Graph API as follows:

```
const auth = getAuth();
getRedirectResult(auth)
    .then( result => {
        const accessToken = result.credential.accessToken;
        localStorage.set('accessToken', accessToken);
        console.log(accessToken); });
```

You'll likely want to play around with the MS graph API on the commandline with curl:

```bash
access_token=<copy/ paste from browser as needed>
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}" -H "Content-Type: image/jpg" https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserName@outlook.com/photos/360x360/\$value --output /tmp/out.jpg
```

It's important to take note that testing Microsoft APIs with bash can be precarious! The `$` in MS's rest API needs to be escaped in your shell or the command will return some confusing json instead of the image binary.  Also, modern versions of curl will fail to print the binary data unless the `--output` switch is used.

A complete implementation on the frontend of pulling in MS Azure Profile pics might look something like below.

```js
const lookupMsAzureProfilePhoto = (accessToken) => {
  fetch('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'
    }
  })
    .then(async function(response) {
      return await response.blob();
    })
    .then(function(blob) {
      const imageObjectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      // imageObjectURL will be e.g. blob:http://localhost:3000/f123c12a-1234-4e30-4321-af32f2c5e5bc
      // so updating the <img scr=""> will present the image correctly after
      // this function runs
      // setProfilePicUrl(imageObjectURL);
    })
    .catch(e => console.log('error injecting photo'));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth):

> Unlike other providers supported by Firebase Auth, Microsoft does not
> provide a photo URL and instead, the binary data for a profile photo
> has to be requested via Microsoft Graph API.